# Identificar datos del web.config en razor

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

Necesito ayuda para como identificar una bandera del web.config en un archivo cshtml es decir:

Que este codigo que se encuentra en el web.config:

```
<!--Identificador de sesion (Si es prueba en desarrollo o es QA/Producción)-->
<add key="ambients" value="1"/>
```

¿Lo puede hacer que se identifique dentro de la pagina en razor.?

Que haga lo mismo que hace esto:

```
string Ambientes = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ambients"].ToString();
```

Pero identificandolo en razor.

Saludos  pdt espero y mi pregunta este bien formulada.

Comment: En lugar de ambients, utiliza environments. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes poner ese valor en el ViewBag, y en la vista consultarlo desde ahí:

C#

```
ViewBag.Ambientes = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ambients"].ToString();
```

Razor

```
@{ var Ambientes = ViewBag.Ambientes.ToString(); }
```

--

Para solo enviar un ambiente:

C#

```
var ambientesFromConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ambients"].ToString(); //"dev,test,prod";
var ambientes = ambientesFromConfig.Split(',');
var ambiente = ambientes[0];
ViewBag.Ambiente = ambiente;
```

No sé, cualquier código que ayude. El truco es poner la variable que necesites en tu vista en el ViewBag.

Comment: Si pero como podria mas que nada hacer que identifique si es uno y si es otro valor?

Comment: Pon cualquier código c# que necesites antes de configurar tu ViewBag.